# Getting String from a Spinner

Tags: android, string, spinner, selecteditem

So I've been following some advice around similar questions and I somehow couldn't manage to get into it. I have a spinner called 'e' from which I want to retrieve the selected string when the user clicks a button below it.

I implemented the nested class like this:

```
class SelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
                String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){
                //does nothing
            }
        }
        e.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SelectedListener());
```

Just following the advice from other users around here and the android developers tutorial, the thing is, after this, I don't know which call should I make to retrieve it if I want to save it into a String variable like so:

```
String selected = //don't know what to put here
```

Hope is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure:

```
e.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

Comment: That's what I was doing before looking out for help and my app crashes when I do so :(

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the LogCat so we can diagnose the issue.

Comment: Solved, the origin from the crash was not that, I can actually make it work using _String selected = e.getSelectedItem().toString();_ which makes me wonder why all the nested class stuff?